# colocation of a server

Tags: virtualization, ip-address, datacenter, colocation, virtuozzo

Hi I currently host my site we a hosting provider and that is going well, however they have just been sold and I want to use a server (either Poweredge 6850 or Poweredge 2950) which will be put inside a datacentre.

Here is what I am needing more information about, or maybe more understanding.

The end result will be 4 VPS servers:
3 x MongoDB database servers
1 x cPanel servers.

I understand that I would need software like Virtuozzo, but do I need addition software before this?

1) Like how do I tell which IP address goes to which VPS (I mean do I need per 1 IP address = 1 network card?)

2) As I'll need 4 IP addresses do I need to buy them from [APNIC](https://www.apnic.net/) or does the datacenter supply these already?

3) Since what I want to do is run and control 4 VPS servers, would I need another server rack above that doing firewalls, or would Centos and Virtuozzo have firewalls which are standard for hosting companies.

**NOTE** This is the first time I have thought about hosting a server in a datacentre - and I know if I was to do this at home, the way I would do it. But is it the same set up in a datacenter or very different?

Comment: Your understanding of basic concepts is non existent to too shallow. Your question is too broad. These do not make for a good question on SF. More importantly they generally make for an owned system contributing to a global botnet. If you want to move away from a shared hosting provider (which is probably not a good idea for you at your level of understanding) the try moving one site to a VPS and see how you get on.

Comment: We use a VPS server already - not shared server @istheEnglishway

Answer (score 3):

1. You only *need* one interface, put it in bridged mode and then connect the virtual interfaces of the VMs to the bridge.
2. You need to get them from the hoster. APNIC wouldn't even talk to you.
3. You can run appropriate FW software on CentOS.
4. Dump CPanel. Learn to do it real without crutches.
5. Until you learned that, better forget to host your own server in a DC and continue to rent VMs. This will most likely also be considerable cheaper.